# Number formating in R and textplot

Tags: r, format, number-formatting

I have a dataframe that I want to print out using `textplot`.  I am using the basic `summary()` function as an example.  `daily` has the series of data, I haven´t uploaded it because I´m not sure its necessasry for the help, please let me know if you need it:

```
result = (summary(as.data.frame(daily[,1])))
print(result)
 sma          
 Min.   :-8285.31  
 1st Qu.: -614.66  
 Median :    0.00  
 Mean   :   27.33  
 3rd Qu.:  738.05  
 Max.   : 8879.92
```

I would like to format the numbers so that a "," separates the thousands. As an example the Min.: item would show up as -8,285.31 instead of 8285.31.

Also, I am using the `textplot` function to print out the plot:

```
textplot(format.df((result), na.blank=TRUE, numeric.dollar=FALSE, 
     cdec=rep(0,dim(result)[1])), 
     rmar = 0.8, 
     cmar = 1,  
     max.cex=.9, halign = "center", valign = "top", 
     row.valign="center", wrap.rownames=20, wrap.colnames=10, 
     col.rownames=c( rep("black",12)), 
     mar = c(0,0,3,0)+0.1)
```

It would be great to know where I can do this formatting.

Thanks,

Augusto

Comment: Did you try `format(result, big.mark=",", scientific=FALSE)`?

Comment: Sample data is needed, something like `dput( head( daily,12 ) )` or so will help.